# Instrument exogeneity assumption (IV)

Tags: self-study, instrumental-variables

The simple regression model is

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x + u$,

where $Cov(x,u) \neq 0$. To obtain consistent estimators of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ when $x$ and $u$ are correlated, we can use $z$ as an instrumental variable for $x$. The instrument has to satisfy the following two assumptions:

$Cov(z,u)=0$

and

$Cov(z,x)\neq 0$

Wooldridge now writes: "instrument exogeneity means that $z$ should have no partial effect on $y$ (after x and ommited variables have been controlled for), and $z$ should be uncorrelated with the omitted variables."

I don't understand how the first assumption, $Cov(z,u)=0$, implies that $z$ has no partial effect on $y$, and why this is necessary. I understand that if $z$ were correlated with $u$ then $z$ would be endogenous and we couldn't obtain consistent estimators of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$. I just don't get why $z$ should have no partial effect on $y$ to be a valid instrument. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand that correlation between $z$ and $u$ would be problematic, the covariance assumption follows quite naturally. Correlation is just covariance divided by the product of the standard deviations, which are both positive numbers. If correlation is zero, the covariance must be zero as well. If the covariance is not zero, the correlation will inherit that.

The intuition is that you need $z$ to wiggle around $x$ (relevance), but without also altering $u$ in the process (exogeneity). That partial variation is what identifies $\beta_1$ consistently. If $z$ was also moving around $u$, you would be back near where you started. IV only uses part of the variation in $x$, the part that's uncorrelated with $u$ and is induced by $z$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  But why is $z$ not allowed to be correlated with $y$?

Comment: z can be correlated with y only through x, but not with u.

Comment: If $z$ would be directly correlated with $y$, then we couldn't distinguish between the effect that $z$ has directly on $y$ and the effect that $x$ has indirectly on $y$ (via $z$). Is this the reason why $z$ is only allowed to affect $y$ indirectly?

Comment: @S.Ming I think this requirement is also about bias. IV throws away some of the variation in $x$, and only uses the good part of the variation that is induced by the instrument $z$ to estimate the effect of $x$ on $y$. If the instrument was correlated with something in $u$, then this discarding cannot happen. That is one way to $z$ cannot alter $y$. The instrument cannot also alter $y$ directly (say through a non-zero $\gamma z$ term in the $y$ equation), for the reasons you stated.

Answer (score 2):

If $z$ had a partial effect on $y$, i.e. not just "through $x$," you would have to include it in your main regression equation. That's why $Cov(z,u)=0$ is also known as the "exclusion restriction." You are excluding $z$ from your linear model for $y$ because you assume that it has no partial effect on $y$ after controlling for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I also puzzled over this and struggled to find answers, but one of my econometrics lecturers explained it quite well.

I give a brief primer on the IV estimator before answering your question and relating to the 'validity' condition for IV estimators.

Consider the model (in design-matrix notation)

$$Y=X\beta+u$$

We can derive the estimator,
$$\hat{\beta}_\textrm{OLS}=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$$

from OLS, but we can also derive it from the moment condition for exogeneity of $X$,

$$E[X'u]=0.$$

When that exogeneity of $X$ is violated we use a set of exogenous instruments, $W$, (some of which might feature in $X$),

$$\hat{\beta} _\textrm{IV}=(W'X)^{-1}W'Y.$$

Then we see there are two conditions for $\hat{\beta}_\textrm{IV}$ to be unbiased,

\begin{align}
&\mathrm{(i)}\text{ Validity: }E[W'u]=0\\
&\mathrm{(ii)}\text{ Relevance: }E[W'X]\neq 0
\end{align}

and for consistency,

$$\mathrm{(i)}\operatorname{plim}\left(\frac{1}{N}W'u\right)=0$$
$$\mathrm{(ii)}\operatorname{ lim}\left(\frac{1}{N}W'X\right)\neq 0$$

(i) goes without saying, it is why we instrument in the first place. (ii) says that $W$ and $X$ cannot be orthogonal, they must be correlated because otherwise the inverse, $(W'X)^{-1}$, doesn't exist, and we can't obtain an estimator. (As an aside, if $E[W'X\approx 0]$ we have a *weak* instrument problem, although unbiased the estimator has high variance. As a rule of thumb, [Staiger and Stock (1997)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2171753) recommend in regression of $X$ on $W$ we require F statistic > 10.)

Having established the basic properties of the estimator, we get to the heart of your question: ***why do we say excluded instruments (those in $W$ but not in $X$) can only have an effect on $Y$ through $X$?***

Suppose we posit the model

$$Y=X\beta+u$$

where we think some of the $X$ are endogenous and so we instrument with $W=Z+X_\textrm{ex}$, where $W$ is the instrument matrix, $Z$ are excluded instruments, and $X_\textrm{ex}$ are the exogenous $X$. But the *true* model is

$$Y=X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon$$

That is, our excluded instruments have a partial effect on $Y$ not through $X$. Then for our IV estimator

\begin{align*}
E\left[\hat{\beta}_\textrm{IV}\right]&=E[(W'X)^{-1}W'Y]\\
&=E[(W'X)^{-1}W'(X\beta + Z\gamma+\epsilon)\\
&=E[(W'X)^{-1}W'X\beta] + E[(W'X)^{-1}W'Z\gamma])+E[(W'X)^{-1}W'\epsilon])\\
&=\beta+E[(W'X)^{-1}W'Z\gamma]\neq\beta
\end{align*}

We have introduced a bias. Why? If $Z$ has a partial effect on $Y$ not through $X$, then when $Z$ is 'big' we have $Y$ is big, since $Z$ is missing from our model, this means that it works through $u$ ('big' $Z$, big $u$). This is just like omitted variable bias. $Z$ is actually endogenous in our posited model (correlated with $u$) even if is exogenous in the true model (uncorrelated with $\epsilon$), so our model is mis-specified and the validity condition (i) is violated.

Dropping matrix notation and opting for an even simpler model, suppose we posit the model with only 1 regressor,

$$y=\beta x + u$$

We think $x$ is endogenous and instrument it with only 1 instrument $z$, but the *true* model is

$$y=\beta x + \gamma z +\epsilon$$

We have

\begin{align*}
E\left[\hat{\beta}_\textrm{IV}\right]&=\frac{\sum_i z_i y_i}{\sum_i x_i z_i}\\
&=E\left[\frac{\sum_i z_i (\beta x + \gamma z +\epsilon)}{\sum_i x_i z_i}\right]\\
&=E\left[\beta\frac{\sum_i x_i z_i}{\sum_i x_i z_i}+\gamma\frac{\sum_i z_i^2}{\sum_i x_i z_i}+\frac{\sum_i z_i\epsilon}{\sum_i x_i z_i}\right]\\
&=\beta+\gamma E\left[\frac{\sum_i z_i^2}{\sum_i x_i z_i}\right]\neq \beta
\end{align*}

and so we see the size of the bias depends on the partial effect $\gamma$. (Also note that if we have a weak instrument - see above - then the denominator $x_iz_i$ is small and can have large bias even for small $\gamma$.)

Comment: Hi Philip. Your posts are appreciable (+1 to both). I have taken some liberty to format your equations. Please check that. Feel free to change. Hoping for more frequent contribution from you here.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for the edits, my LaTeX wan't quite up to scratch back then.